# How to open an html page from java script as a bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am developing a chrome extension and want to open an HTML page from content script as a bootstrap modal on the same page. How is it possible?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please [edit] the question to add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is a bit vague and you didn't provide any code which isn't the best to do.

But you can achieve this using [iFrames](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Your modal body would have somthing like `<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>` in it.

All the information you'd need is on that site. But you'd possibly need to update some CSS to make it look good.

Comment: to be on-topic, show attempts (code) and specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I created a full screen modal with scrollable iframe and when the modal active the body scroll capabilty has been disabale and when modal close scroll has been enable.I hope this will help. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="mybody">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="disablebodyscroll()"> OOPEN A MODAL WITH IFRAME</button>
    <div style="background-color: black; height: 800px;"></div>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Ace</p>
    <!-- End of button trigger modal -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="enablebodyscroll()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" width="100%" height="100%" position="absolute" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<style type="text/css">
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.modal-body {
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disablebodyscroll() {
    document.getElementById("mybody").style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function enablebodyscroll() {
    document.getElementById("mybody").style.overflow = "auto";
}
</script>
```